# What font does Antergos use?

Tags: terminal, fonts, antergos

I've just started using Antergos at work and I like its default fonts. I'm especially interested in the one in the terminal. Does anybody know what its name is? I've tried googling and had no luck.

I use Arch Linux at home. I'd like to use Antergos terminal font with it.

Comment: What fonts *where*? TTY, GTK/QT, terminals?

Comment: Terminal. I've edited the question to be more precise

Answer (score 1):

This is the default Font settings from my Antergos Installation:

[image: Antergos Default Font Screenshot]

Basically `Sans Regular` and `Monospace Regular`. And all fonts are Truetype Fonts

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I believe Cantarell is the font you are referring to.

Comment: The question was "Does anybody know what its name is?" My answer is Cantarell. How does that "not provide an answer to the question"?

Comment: Oh sorry, when I reviewed your post I thought you were commenting on OP's question instead of answering it.